# Distinguish between transpose and command string in Julia lexer

Tags: julia, antlr, antlr4, lexer

For my thesis I am implementing a parser/lexer for Julia, however some areas are being a bit of a problem.

For background Julia has a special token that gives the transpose (`), also there is 'command string' that uses this same token to wrap the string (`command`). The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get a regex that will match properly.

i.e.
this should match for a transpose:

`` a` ``

as well as

`` a` b` ``

and

```
a`
b`
```

and this should match the command string

`` `a` ``
and also:

```
` a
b `
```

The issue I'm having is that either, when there's 2 transposes in a file it will match the command string, or when there is new line in a command string then the parser will fail as both are seen as only a transpose, to me this seems like they are mutually exclusive.

The regexes in the order in which they are in the lexer are:

option 1:

```
COMMAND
    : '`' (ESC|.)*? '`'
    ;
```

```
 TRANSPOSE
    : '\'' | '`'
    ;
```

option 2:

```
COMMAND
    : '`' ( '\\' | ~[\\\r\n\f] )* '`'
    ;
```

```
 TRANSPOSE
    : '\'' | '`'
    ;
```

Comment: Can it be done in the lexer at all? What are the exact rules when `\`` is supposed to be a transpose-char, and when it's supposed to be a part of a command string?

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. The transpose operator is the apostrophe `'` (U+0027 ' APOSTROPHE), and command literals are within backticks (U+0060 \` GRAVE ACCENT).

Comment: Although that's not gonna change much about having to parse `a'b'` as `a`-adjoint times `b`-adjoint as opposed to `a` followed by the character `'b'`.

Comment: Indeed @phipsgabler I think you are correct, I was basing it off of random files I pulled off github to test, which may not have been smart as there is no guarantee that they are correct, however this does bring the problem pfitzseb mentioned

Comment: Yeah I realized the same problem exists with `'` :D I had a look at src/julia-parser.scm to see how it's done. But that won't help you very much -- it's a hand-written stream processor thing, and the two cases buried down in special-cased code.

Comment: Can you add something to explain, in text, how you would know when something is a transpose and when something is a command?  That would help a lot.  I appears that is *may* be whitespace related, but knowing how to tell the difference will really help in figuring out how to resolve the ambiguity in ANTLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, the transpose operator in Julia is actually `'`, rather than `` ` ``. What has not been noted yet is there is at least one one critical diffence between how `'` is used and how `` ` `` is used) that makes your job a lot easier. Specifically:

- Unlike `` ` ``, which may be used to quote command strings of *any* length, `'` is only ever used to quote characters. Consequently, the only valid uses of `'` as a quotation are of single characters (e.g. `` `a` ``) or one of the special ANSI escape sequences beginning with `\` such as `` `\n` `` for newline (the full list being to my knowledge `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v`, `` \` ``, `\"`, and `\\`).

Consequently, the `'`s in a sequence like `[a' b']`can only possibly be interpreted as transposes since `' b'` is not a valid `Char`

- While juxtaposition can be taken to mean multiplication in Julia, and multiplication can in turn be used to concatenate strings in Julia (long story -- string concatenation is the associative, noncommutative binary operation of a [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) and thus analogous to multiplication), juxtaposition is not currently allowed as a way to multiply strings or characters.

Consequently, a sequence like `a'b'` can only be interpreted as `a' * b'` and not `a * 'b'`.

Combining these two more broadly, unless I am missing some edge case, it appears that a new `'` following any character *other than* whitespace, parentheses, or a valid [infix operator](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/list-of-binary-infix-operators/32282), is always parsed as transpose, rather than the opening quote of a character literal.